# If one uses Unicode for UI symbols, is there a better choice for a hamburger menu than U+2261 (≡, "Identical to")?

Tags: user-interface, unicode, menu, symbols

I noticed that there are plenty of common UI symbols already in Unicode, even a symbol for overlapping window frames. But I really had to dig for a triple-bar symbol like what's become universally recognized as a collapsed menu. I did find U+2261 (≡) and decide to use it in my projects, but after looking further, I found that it's in the mathematical symbols block, and that its meaning is typically "identical to" or "congruent." So perhaps the symbol isn't quite the perfect one.

Does this matter? I don't really think so, but, it might throw off screen readers, so perhaps I should find something better. If it matters, I'm intending to use this in a web app.

Comment: I can see the `≡` (or alike) symbol in Firefox for _Open menu_ while Chrome uses either MathSymbol `⋮` (U+22EE  _Vertical Ellipsis_)  or OtherPunctuation `︙`  (U+FE19 _Presentation Form For Vertical Horizontal Ellipsis_). Edge seems to use OtherPunctuation `…` (U+2026     _Horizontal Ellipsis_) for he same purposes… Firefox uses Horizontal Ellipsis (or alike) for _Page actions_ inside the address bar.

Comment: @JosefZ, can you tell if it's the actual unicode symbol or just an image that looks similar? That's neat though.

Comment: @NomadVoxel obviously it's a Unicode character. You can't post images in a comment

Comment: @phuclv not in the comment, in the apps he cites. come on I'm not *that* stupid...

Answer (score 1):

Someone actually has the same thought as yours

> ## Which is best?
>
> I’d probably avoid the Unicode symbol as it doesn’t have the correct semantic meaning. I’d probably avoid making an HTTP request for an image just for this. The gradient thing is nice, but it’s a good size chunk of code to maintain.
>
> I’d probably go for inline SVG.
>
> [Hamburger Menu Icons (Three Line Menu Icon / Navicon) Different Ways](https://css-tricks.com/three-line-menu-navicon/)

I don't think there are any Unicode for representing the menu icon, because when Unicode was first designed people usually use graphical symbols in GUI mode, and in text mode there's only a limited set of special symbols and it'll be silly to waste a codepoint for the menu icon when you can just use text. If you opt for using Unicode characters then there are many equivalent glyphs like [☰ trigram for heaven (U+2630)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2630/index.htm) or  counting rod unit digit three (U+1D362). IMHO it's also better to use inline SVG with an alt text for screen readers

See also

- [7 Non-Raster Approaches for Making the “Hamburger” Menu Icon](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/7-non-raster-approaches-for-making-the-hamburger-menu-icon--cms-21686)
- [The Semantic, Responsive Navicon](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/the-semantic-responsive-design-navicon/)

Comment: Compare this to other icons that do have Unicode equivalents, such as U+1F50D for the "search icon".  Moreover, new characters and symbols are added to the Unicode Standard every year, and it's possible that a menu icon or other "user interface icons" could be proposed for addition to a future version of that standard.

Comment: @PeterO. that U+1F50D is called "magnifying glass" and not "search", and it exists in Unicode just because it's been used by Japanese mobile phone carriers before, as indicated by [emoji sources](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/EmojiSources.txt). It's the same reason [the “copyright”, “registered trademark” and “trademark” symbols are considered emojis](https://superuser.com/q/1602766/241386)